# Showing Invalid Email in CakePHP

Tags: email, cakephp

Hi please check my CakePHP code.

**Code**

```
    //$from="my_email@domain.com";
    $from="CakePHP Email<my_email@domain.com>";
    $to="someone_email@domain.com";
    $sendMessage="This is CakePHP test message";
    $sendMessage =$message;
    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->template('default')
        ->emailFormat('html')
        ->to($to)
        ->from($from)
        ->bcc('learnphpchinu@gmail.com')
        ->subject('CakePHP test subject')
        ->send($sendMessage);           
    return true;
```

This email is not working properly. I am getting error message "Invalid email address `CakePHP Email<my_email@domain.com>`".

If i have used `my_email@domain.com` instead of `CakePHP Email<my_email@domain.com>` the email working fine but the from email is showing `my_email` in mail box.

I want to show `CakePHP Email` in my from email address. How could i fix that issue. Help me?

Comment: check this answer for sending email in cakephp

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490250/sending-email-with-cakeemail/13493005#13493005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it takes array as an argument for from name,change your `$from` to

```
$from = array('my_email@domain.com' => 'CakePHP Email');
```

*[Reference](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html)*.

Answer (score -2):

Try this >

```
  if (filter_var($d['email_to'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

                    $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
                    $this->Email->from = $d['email_from'];
                    $this->Email->to = $d['email_to'];
                    $this->Email->subject = $d['subject'];
                    $this->Email->send($d['message']);
            }
```

Comment: public $components = array('Email');

Comment: Please read my question again.. I got my answer. Thanks for tried.